# Joomla 3.5 - modify "List All Categories" menu item style

Tags: templates, joomla, overriding

with my students we are creating a portfolio artist site. we would like to have the Joomla categories listet in four rows with the bootstrap class"span3".

There for we need a template override for the com_content/views/categories/tmpl/ files like in the category blog.

Any help is higly appreciated.
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Kindly open file from the below path

Root==>templates==>yourtemplatename==>html==>com_content==>categories==>default_items.php

Remove all code and paste the below code

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

JHtml::_('bootstrap.tooltip');

$class = ' class="span3"';
$lang  = JFactory::getLanguage();

$cols = 3;
$_cols  = 0;
$clear_class = '<div class="clearfix" style="clear:both;"></div>';  

if (count($this->items[$this->parent->id]) > 0 && $this->maxLevelcat != 0) :
?>
    <?php foreach($this->items[$this->parent->id] as $id => $item) : ?>
        <?php
        if ($this->params->get('show_empty_categories_cat') || $item->numitems || count($item->getChildren())) :
        if (!isset($this->items[$this->parent->id][$id + 1]))
        {
            //$class = ' class="span3 last"';           
        }       
        if($_cols >= $cols) {
                echo $clear_class;              
            $_cols = 1;
        } else {
            ++$_cols;
        }       
        ?>
        <div <?php echo $class; ?> >
        <?php $class; ?>
            <h3 class="page-header item-title">
                <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($item->id, $item->language));?>">
                <?php echo $this->escape($item->title); ?></a>
                <?php if ($this->params->get('show_cat_num_articles_cat') == 1) :?>
                    <span class="badge badge-info tip hasTooltip" title="<?php echo JHtml::tooltipText('COM_CONTENT_NUM_ITEMS'); ?>">
                        <?php echo $item->numitems; ?>
                    </span>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if (count($item->getChildren()) > 0 && $this->maxLevelcat > 1) : ?>
                    <a id="category-btn-<?php echo $item->id;?>" href="#category-<?php echo $item->id;?>"
                        data-toggle="collapse" data-toggle="button" class="btn btn-mini pull-right"><span class="icon-plus"></span> </a>
                <?php endif;?>
            </h3>
            <?php if ($this->params->get('show_description_image') && $item->getParams()->get('image')) : ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $item->getParams()->get('image'); ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($item->getParams()->get('image_alt')); ?>" />
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($this->params->get('show_subcat_desc_cat') == 1) :?>
                <?php if ($item->description) : ?>
                    <div class="category-desc">
                        <?php echo JHtml::_('content.prepare', $item->description, '', 'com_content.categories'); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (count($item->getChildren()) > 0 && $this->maxLevelcat > 1) :?>
                <div class="collapse fade" id="category-<?php echo $item->id;?>">
                <?php
                $this->items[$item->id] = $item->getChildren();
                $this->parent = $item;
                $this->maxLevelcat--;
                echo $this->loadTemplate('items');
                $this->parent = $item->getParent();
                $this->maxLevelcat++;
                ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Josef,

thank you very much for the quick and helpful answer. it works out of the box! there are only two little problems. we are using the protostar template where the first span in a row gets the class .row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child with a margin: 0. is it possible to get this class after the a row is full and the <div class="clearfix" style="clear:both;"></div>?

when all items are rendered there would be a clearfix nice. so it doesn't mess up the rest of the site.

thanks peter

Comment: You can overwrite css `div.categories-list.span3:first-child{margin:10px;}` and clearfix is right,meaning as clear:both you can remove

Comment: hi josef, i played around and found a working solution for me. i changed your code in line 11 from >> $clear_class = '<div class="clearfix" style="clear:both;"></div>';  <<  to  >> $clear_class = '</div><div class="categories-list clearfix">';  <<. now i have the class first-child after each row.